# How to get updated variable in class?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    some_variable = None

    def __init__(self, args):
        data = infile.read()
        self.some_variable= int.from_bytes(data[0:4], byteorder="big", signed=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("input_file", "rb") as infile:
        MyClass(infile)
        print(MyClass.some_variable)
```

This prints None, how do I do this?

Comment: You're ignoring the instance and accessing the previous attribute value on the class. It's unclear what you're really trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'm trying to get the variable from the instance.

Comment: The instance is returned by `MyClass(infile)` and completely ignored in your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access an instance of the class not the class itself

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("input_file", "rb") as infile:
        my_class = MyClass(infile)
        print(my_class.some_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, args):
    data = infile.read()
    self.some_variable= int.from_bytes(data[0:4], byteorder="big", signed=False)
```

So your `self.some_variable` is called an *"instance's attribute"*, and you can access it from an instance:

```
my_instance_of_MyClass = MyClass(infile)
print(my_instance_of_MyClass.some_variable)
```

---

I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) to better understand the difference between `class variables` and `instance variables`.